# Incorrect Monitor resolution linux mint 19.3 32 bit

Tags: linux, drivers, linux-mint, resolution, 32-bit

When I installed linux mint 19.3 on 32 bit system the monitor resolution was fine and everything worked as normal. But suddenly yesterday the monitor resolution has shrunk down to `4:3` aspect ratio and everything appears very big.

My actual monitor resolution is `1920x1080`

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not able to change resolution from display settings, I think there is some driver issue. What could be possible solution for this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: First of all, an Intel Core2Duo is a 64-bit CPU therefore you should using a 64-bit OS. the 32-bit architecture is being phased out.